# SWIFT + Parse signUpInBackgroundWithBlock no longer works: Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.3.1

I'm using the latest parse code from the parse.com for   `user.signupInBackgroundWithBlock`

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
               self.showAlertWithText(message: "\(error)")
            } else {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("createNewUserAndGoToDashboard", sender: self)
            }
```

I just upgraded to x-code 6.3.1 and it no longer works.  This is copied directly from Parse.com, but I'm getting an error on the user.signUp line:

1.0/SIgnUpViewController.swift:48:46: Function signature `'(Bool?, NSError?) -> Void'` is not compatible with expected type

```
'@objc_block (Bool, NSError!) -> Void'
```

any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried it without the "?" after the Bool

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
                self.showAlertWithText(message: "\(error)")
            } else {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("createNewUserAndGoToDashboard", sender: self) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (returnedResult, returnedError) -> Void in
        if returnedError == nil
        {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            self.showAlert("There was an error with your sign up", error: returnedError!)
        }
    }
```