# Swift - Parse "Signing Up" error

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
var user = PFUser()
    user.username = username.text
    user.password = password.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if signupError == nil  {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.

                println("signed up")
```

I'm getting an error at `user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {`

It says:

> Function signature (Bool!, NSError!) -> is not compatible with expected type @obj_block (Bool, NSError!) - > Void

This code is from a tutorial video. The current "Signing Up" code from Parse looks different from this code

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892933/swift-parse-signupinbackgroundwithblock-no-longer-works-xcode-6-3-1

Answer (score 0):

`succeeded` should be a bool not an optional. Remove the exclamation point like so:

`(succeeded: Bool, signupError: NSError!)`